# Develop iPhone/iPad application on Hackintosh

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, hackintosh

I'm wordering if I develop iphone and ipad application, does that application work on a non-jailbreak iphone ipad? Because I've heard someone said that if I develop application with Hackintosh, I cannot upload my application to appStore, and it only works for jailbreak iphone/ipad

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No. it will work on all iPhones/iPads. I have created and uploaded on iTunes. not face any problem.

Comment: @Mitesh just curious. Do u install hackinstosh on ur own ? How tough is it ?

Comment: @Mitesh Hi again. Thax for your information. I need few more info if you wish to help. How tough is it to install? What do we need for that ?

Comment: Its very simple. just need a intel pc and Snow Leopard iATKOS DVD.

Comment: I have intel945 and it works for me. if you need any other help then drop me a maail.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of installing Hackintosh, compare with install an offical Mac OS using iBoot?

Comment: Different hardware have different hackintosh and different cracks. thx